# Call to a member function load() on a non-object in

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.9.2.0

When I change the status of brands in the leftpanel extension I get this error and it doesnt change the status Line 180 is this code `->load($leftpanelId)`

> Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in
>   /home/thebeau9/public_html/app/code/local/Nextgeni/Leftpanel/controllers/Adminhtml/BrandsController.php
>   on line 180

```
public function massStatusAction()
{
    $leftpanelIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('leftpanel');
    if(!is_array($leftpanelIds)) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Please select item(s)'));
    } else {
        try {
            foreach ($leftpanelIds as $leftpanelId) {
                $leftpanel = Mage::getSingleton('leftpanel/leftpanel')
                    ->load($leftpanelId)
                    ->setStatus($this->getRequest()->getParam('status'))
                    ->setIsMassupdate(true)
                    ->save();
            }
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                $this->__('Total of %d record(s) were successfully updated', count($leftpanelIds))
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/index');
}
```

Config.xml

```
<global>
    <models>
        <leftpanel>
            <class>Nextgeni_Leftpanel_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>leftpanel_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </leftpanel>
        <leftpanel_mysql4>
            <class>Nextgeni_Leftpanel_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <brand>
                    <table>leftpanel_brand</table>
                </brand>
                <treatment>
                    <table>leftpanel_treatment</table>
                </treatment>
                <ingredient>
                    <table>leftpanel_ingredient</table>
                </ingredient>
            </entities>
        </leftpanel_mysql4>
        <!-- Paypal config model override - Gk on 03-08-2015 -->
        <paypal>
            <rewrite>
                <!-- Model -->
                <config>Nextgeni_Leftpanel_Model_Config</config>
            </rewrite>
        </paypal>
        <!-- Paypal config model override - Gk on 19-08-2015 -->
        <paypal>
```

leftpanel.php in model

```
 class Nextgeni_Leftpanel_Block_Leftpanel extends Mage_Core_Block_Template

 {

 public function _prepareLayout()
{
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

 public function getLeftpanel()     
 { 
    if (!$this->hasData('leftpanel')) {
        $this->setData('leftpanel', Mage::registry('leftpanel'));
    }
    return $this->getData('leftpanel');

}

}
```

Brand.php in model

```
<?php

class Nextgeni_Leftpanel_Model_Brand extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract

{

public function _construct()
     {
             parent::_construct();
             $this->_init('leftpanel/brand');
     }
 }
```

Comment: could you please post the content of your `app/code/local/Nextgeni/Leftpanel/etc/config.xml` ?

Comment: @Raphael config.xml is added.

Comment: Great and what is the content of `app/code/local/Nextgeni/Leftpanel/Model/Leftpanel.php` ?

Comment: Which table you have tried to update?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism added the leftpanel.php file.

Comment: Not the block, the model please ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism Just looked at the file. this is the leftpanelphp file in the model folder, I realize it is a block file but no other file with the same name is uploaded on the server unfortunately

Comment: Well that's where your problem is coming from.

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I have added the brand.php model file but that pretty much has a constructor to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you get such error :

> Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object

After calling `Mage::getModel('foo/bar')` that means that the class corresponding to `foo/bar` does not exist.

### What to check

Checks that `foo` is declared in your module `config.xml` in the `model` node:

```
<global>
    <models>
        <foo>
            <class>Vendor_Module_Model</class>
        </foo>
    </model>
</global>
```

Checks that `bar` is an existing model under your `Model` folder: `app/code/<codePool>/Vendor/Module/Model/Bar.php`

### In your case

Magento is looking for `app/code/local/Nextgeni/Leftpanel/Model/Leftpanel.php` but according to your comment, you don't have such file.

I'm not sure what your code is doing and you posted the content of a `app/code/local/Nextgeni/Leftpanel/Model/Brand.php` so I will assume that's the model that needed to be used in your controller.

Thus you can fix your problem by replacing:

```
$leftpanel = Mage::getSingleton('leftpanel/leftpanel')
```

With:

```
$leftpanel = Mage::getSingleton('leftpanel/brand')
```